# sort.Sort not modifying array

Tags: go

The following code should create an array of ints (`a`) and sort it, but sort.Sort does not appear to modify the variable.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type IntArray [5]int

type byNum [5]int
func (s byNum) Len() int {
    return len(s)
}
func (s byNum) Swap(i, j int) {
    s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
}
func (s byNum) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return s[i] < s[j]
}

func main() {
    a := IntArray{5,3,4,1,2}

    fmt.Println(a)
    sort.Sort(byNum(a))
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/bhcwgosqvis

```
[5 3 4 1 2]
[5 3 4 1 2]

Program exited.
```

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the Swap method is changing the argument array, not the array in the caller.

Fix by declaring byNum as a slice:

```
type byNum []int

...

sort.Sort(byNum(a[:]))
```

In this call, the backing array of the slice argument is the array that you want to modify.

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/uyWgR6B-YkH).